# Simple Injector Conditionally Register With Delegates

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm writing an app that makes use of classes defined by the following interface:

```
public interface ICredentialProvider
{
    string GetUsername();
    string GetPassword();
}
```

This is done so methods can be called to retrieve the username/password instead of it being statically held in memory and defined in code/config file.

Currently in development I'm using this very simple implementation:

```
public class FakedCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
{
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;

    public FakedCredentialProvider(string username, string password)
    {
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    public string GetUsername()
    {
        return _username;
    }

    public string GetPassword()
    {
        return _password;
    }
}
```

...which accepts two strings in the constructor. Future (actual) implementations of `ICredentialProvider` will likely need to accept certain strings for connecting to the appropriate external password vault or service (or possibly both; at this point in the project that's unclear).

Further, the project uses multiple instances of `ICredentialProvider` for the various accounts it needs to connect to (such as SharePoint, ActiveDirectory, and Windows Graph).

To these ends I know how to register via a delegate:

```
container.RegisterWebApiRequest(() =>
    new FakedCredentialProvider(fakedSharePointUsername, fakedSharePointPassword));
```

...And how to conditionally register...

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ICredentialProvider), typeof(FakedCredentialProvider),
        context =>
        context.Consumer.Target.Name.ToLower().Contains("sharepoint")
    );
```

...But not how to combine the two.

How does one combine these two approaches? Or alternatively: Is there an better design for situations such as these?

Comment: I think a better design would be to create different interfaces for each credential-provider. The reason for this is that a class which uses a sharepoint-credential-provider won't work correctly with a active-directory-credential-provider. The credential providers are not interchangeable, therefor, differentiate for this in your design.

Comment: @Maarten Well the returned values aren't exchangable, but the external contract is. Not only that but the credentials ultimately will all be stored in Cyberark's Password Vault or a web service, so the SharePoint and AD access (for example) might both use CyberarkPasswordVaultCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider. I feel like if you say _that_ doesn't count as interchangeable (externally they're identical, and share concrete implementations) SOLID-driven Interfaces would never be appropriate.

Comment: Why do you have the ICredentialProvider at all? Why don't you inject those credentials in the class that needs them directly (assuming those values are not runtime values, but configuration values of course).

Comment: @Steven They are not runtime, but hard coding the manner in which the passwords are retrieved (as they can't sit around in memory due to both security concerns and changing password concerns) gives the class a responsibility that's not it's purpose, and an additional reason to change, and further would duplicate the retrieval logic for every class that needs to retrieve credentials. Overall that seems like a big loss to me. Or did I understand incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I fully understand your constraints and design, but the way to do registration of conditional delegates is using one of the `RegisterConditional` overloads that accepts a `Registration` object:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ICredentialProvider),
    Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(() => new FakedCredentialProvider(user, pwd), 
        container),
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name.ToLower().Contains("sharepoint"));
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about the design; sometimes I have a hard time getting my thoughts down in text. I appreciate the answer, Steven.